# Laravel tailoring slash after url

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

I've added a WordPress website inside Laravel application for bloging purpose. Everything is fine but a slash is coming at the end.
Uploaded WordPress files inside blog folder within public directory.

- `https://example.com` - laravel website
- `https://example.com/blog/` - wordpress blog

Please help me to remove tailoring slash from URL.

I've tried too many `.htaccess` rules, but no hope.

current htaccess of laravel


Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and share the existing `.htaccess`

Comment: Are you referring to the trailing slash on `/blog/` or other URLs (as well)? The trailing slash after `/blog/` is arguably mandatory, since this is a physical directory. (The trailing slash could be removed here, but I would recommend against this.)

Comment: @MrWhitecurrently issue only for /blog/,because it's a subdirectory

Comment: @SelVazi htaccess added

Answer (score 0):

There is two possibilities to remove '/' from URL

1. Check the APP_URL in Laravel Website
2. Check the siteurl in WordPress database tables( wp_options and wp_users )